# How to write output of MATLAB to a txt file?

Tags: matlab, output

I would like to write output of Matlab code's result into a `.txt` file.

My code is :

```
for i=1:1000;
  M{i}=rand(1,4)';
end
```

So I try :

```
fid=fopen('M.txt','wt'); 
fprintf(fid,'%.8f\n',M{i}); 
fclose(fid)
```

The result is 1*1000 cell and every cell has 4*1 matrice. But the output file has 1*4000 matrices with this. How can I write column by column to a `.txt` file.

Thanks in advance.

---

[screenshot from matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYC4t.png)

I want to write down all values of matrix like below side by side for 1000 matrices.

```
 0.9572 0.9572 0.9572 0.9572 0.9572 0.9572 0.9572 0.9572 0.9572 0.9572 
 0.4854 0.4854 0.4854 0.4854 0.4854 0.4854 0.4854 0.4854 0.4854 0.4854
 0.8003 0.8003 0.8003 0.8003 0.8003 0.8003 0.8003 0.8003 0.8003 0.8003 
 0.1419 0.1419 0.1419 0.1419 0.1419 0.1419 0.1419 0.1419 0.1419 0.1419
```

Comment: See edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned your MATLAB version is R2019a, you can use [writematrix](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html) directly:

```
>> n = 4;
>> m = rand(1,n);
>> M = repmat(m.',1,1000);
>> writematrix(M,'M.txt','Delimiter','space')
```

Comment: I edited my question, do you have a chance to look again ? @UnbearableLigtness

Comment: Thank you so much!! But I use writematrix(M,'M.txt','Delimiter','tab') and its done.

Answer (score 1):

Your format specifier `*.8f\n` says print each value on a new line. If you want to print the four values as four columns, use a format specifier like this:

```
fprintf(fid,'%.8f %.8f %.8f %.8f\n',M{i});
```

If you want to write just one column of the data at a time, specify which column like this:

```
fprintf(fid,'%.8f\n',M{i}(1));
```

Then you'll have to repeat or loop to do the other 3 columns.

Comment: I edited my question, do you have a chance to look again ?